# How do I position 2 button centrally over a responsive image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have been going through various post with similar dimension to my issue, but none of them meet my needs: I need to position 2 buttons over a responsive image which I'll be going to use as a landing page for a web site so far I manged to place 2 buttons over an image but when resizing it go pear shape, any tip will be appreciated
here is my HTML:

```css
body {
  background-image: url('../Images/Riverfront%20image.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-size: 100%;
}
p {
  color: orange;
}
.img-container {
  height: 60px;
  width: 140px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: -100px 0 0 -190px;
  left: 52%;
  top: 50%;
}
.img-container2 {
  height: 60px;
  width: 140px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: -100px 0 0 -20px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
.btn1 {
  background: rgba(3, 105, 78, 0.7);
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 140px;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: -50px 0 0 -60px;
  left: 62%;
  top: 50%;
}
.btn {
  background: rgba(3, 105, 78, 0.7);
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 140px;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;
  left: 57%;
  top: 50%;
}
.splash_header {
  /* background-image: url('../Images/webLogo.png');*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-size: 20%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid ">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="splash_header">

      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <img src="../Images/webLogo.png" alt="my website logo">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end splash_header -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="img-container">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="Cym">
          <input class="btn " type="button" value="Arabic" name="Button1" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="img-container2">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input class="btn1 " type="button" value="English" name="Button2" />
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

P.s: I have put the image as a background Image for the body tag does that advisable or there is another way I could do that?

Comment: I've done these things many times before. Can you please upload the image? it doesn't seem to be loading

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
body {
  background-image: url('../Images/Riverfront%20image.jpg');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:contain;
  background-size:100%;
}
p {
    color: orange;
}
.img-container {
  display: table;
  margin:auto;
}

.btn1{   
  background: rgba(3,105, 78, 0.7);
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  width:140px;
  height:60px;
}
.btn {
  background: rgba(3,105, 78, 0.7);
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
   width:140px;
  height:60px;
}
.btn-container {
  display: inline-block;
  float:left;
}
.splash_header
{
   /* background-image: url('../Images/webLogo.png');*/
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    z-index: 1;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
     background-size:contain;
     background-size:20%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

with this dom

```
`<div class="container-fluid ">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="splash_header">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <img src="../Images/webLogo.png" alt="my website logo">
            </div>
            <div class="img-container col-sm-12">
              <div class="col-sm-6 btn-container">
                <input class="btn " type="button" value="Arabic" name="Button1" />                
              </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 btn-container">
                  <input class="btn1 "  type="button" value="English" name="Button2" />
                </div>
          </div> 
         </div>
      </div><!-- end splash_header -->       
</div>`
```

check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qm22Lkb6/

Comment: if you want to have an image at the background and keep it responsive try add `background-size: contain;` or `background-size: 100% 100%;`

Answer (score 0):

this how i solved my problem by using skeleton css and internal css

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.lang-box
{
     /*background: #FFFFEB none repeat scroll 0 0;*/
/*   background-color: rgba(114, 107, 125, 0.6);
*/      

background-color:rgba(0,73,26,0.36);
 border: 1px solid #858585;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: gray;
   font-family:"Gill Sans";
   font-weight:500;
    /*cursor: pointer;
*/    display: inline-block;
    font-size: x-large;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width:1500px;
}
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="lang-box four columns offset-by-two">
<p style="text-align:center; margin-bottom:0"><input class="button button-primary" type="button" value="English"/></p></div>
<div class="lang-box four columns ">
<p  style="text-align:center; margin-bottom:0"> <input class="button button-primary" type="button" value="Arabic"/></p></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

use position property to do this.
Suppose you have a div called  and other is  you need to put  over the  then do this:

```
div1{ default properties}
div2{position:absolute;// or relative whatever you want
     top:20px;// or required what you need 
     }
```

Click [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) for more details